# How to retrieve the value of a setting on a Android device in Java

Tags: java, android, settings, barcode-scanner

I would like to retrieve a setting on an Android device equipped with a barcode reader, namely:

```
Settings -> Peripheral Device -> [Barcode] DataWedge Mode
```

The language I'm using is `Java`.

As I need to detect if this mode is activated or not on the device, can you tell me how to retrieve the value of this parameter?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems to be device dependent. Please contact the vendor or reseller of the device. There seems to be an SDK or manual for the device.

Comment: Thank you Kunif.

Comment: Who is the device manufacturer?

Comment: Hi. The device manufacturer is Bluebird. I am wondering if the Zebra TC20 also has such a  "[Barcode] DataWedge Mode". I wish the code I'm writing could work on several portable devices equipped with a barcode reader...